# Is it possible to add "Major ticks" to the Horizontal axis on a Google Sheets chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to set ticks on a Horizontal axis for a line chart using Google Sheets API?
I couldn't find it in Google Sheets API v4 documentation, doubting it's possible, maybe I missed something.

Here's what I want.
[image]

**EDIT**
The values on horizontal axis are strings, not numbers, gridlines work on integers, but not on strings, any way to go around this?

Comment: In the current stage, it seems that "Major ricks" in "Gridlines and ticks" cannot be changed using Sheets API. So, if you want to manage this, how about reporting it as a future request of Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) By the way, if you want to check "Major ricks", when the chart is created, it has already been checked as the default value. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the info. The default chart is not good for me, but I can go without setting this option.

Comment: Been checking the documentation and I have to agree with [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike), submitting a feature request through the [IssueTracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) would be the best option.